# Can not add AWS Resource level permissions to an Particular EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Referring to this [Doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/resource-level-permissions-for-ec2-controlling-management-access-on-specific-instances/)
I have created IAM policy which allows accessing only one EC2 Instance.And I have created an IAM user with the policy with that policy. But when I logged in with that user into my AWS account I got the Error "An error occurred fetching instance data: You are not authorized to perform this operation."

Policy document:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/test": "test"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:AccountNumber:instance/*
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: not enough. You must add describe instance, list instance

Comment: But I gave Complete EC2 actions in the policy. Is it necessary to add that explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add EC2 describe to describe all EC2 resources, then base on other statement to filter resource by tag. 
**But with this policy, other IAM account still viewable other EC2 instances without any permission.**

Here is what you need.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1507182214000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/TAG_NAME": "TAG_VALUE"
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:AWS_REGION:AWS_ACCOUNT:instance/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:DeleteTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BTaun it worked ,but this will allow the user to see the all the instances running in AWS account. Can we restrict the user to see the instances that were tagged with "TAG_VALUE"?

Comment: Im not sure but Im trying on it

Comment: Ok, I got it. I guess we cannot restrict to view other ec2 instance because when IAM account go to EC2 console, they need `EC2 Describe:*` to describe all EC2 instance, after that, based on `restrict by tag:value` to limit the permission. The best way is add 1 more statement to `deny remove/create tag`. I edited my answer

Comment: yes,  ec2 describe* action does not support resource-level permissions.Thank you @BTaun